# Not able to select an item from AutoCompleteTextView dropdown using Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

Following is the snapshot of my AutoCompleteTextView dropdown, from which I'm trying to select 2nd item

[image]

**My Espresso Code:**

```
onView(withId(R.id.searchContainer)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onData(anything())
      .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.searchContainer))
      .atPosition(1)
      .perform(click());
```

But I'm getting following Exception:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id: com.sampleaddressdd.demo:id/searchContainer'
```

**With Espresso Recorder I get following code:**

```
DataInteraction appCompatTextView = onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(childAtPosition(
                        withClassName(is("android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupBackgroundView")),
                        0))
                .atPosition(0);
        appCompatTextView.perform(click());
```

**Dropdown inflater code :**

```
        mSearchView = findViewById(R.id.textSearch);
        mSearchView.setDropDownAnchor(R.id.searchContainer);
        mHttpClient.fetchAddresss(new HttpClient.AddressCallback() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter = new AddressAdapter(MainActivity.this, mAddresss, new AddressAdapter.OnAddressClickCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Address Address) {
                        startActivity(AddressProfileActivity.createIntent(MainActivity.this, Address));
                    }
                });
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mSearchView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally Achieved this with the use of :

```
onView(withText(LOCATION_TO_BE_SEARCHED)) .inRoot(withDecorView(not(mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))) .check(matches(isDisplayed())) .perform(click());
```